# Java - Deleting whole linked-list doesn't affect the actual list

Tags: java, recursion, linked-list

I typed recursive method to delete all the nodes in a simple linked-list but in fact debugger shows this method doesn't affect the actual list and I don't know why it's like that. Here's my code:

```
class List
{ Element root; ...}

class Element
{int value; Element next; ...}


Element delete(Element head)
{
 if(head == null) return null;
 head = delete(head.next);
 return head;
}
```

Comment: How do you call this method? Why do you expect it to delete all the nodes?

Comment: Please show the call of this method that demonstrates that the code is not working properly. Note that since Java is a garbage-collected language, this whole thing is equivalent to `head=null` assignment.

Comment: I've got a list and I call:
Element test = delete(list.head);
And test is obviously null
So is it really that simple? Do I really need to call just method like this:
delete(Element head){ head = null;}?

Comment: And why shouldn't it be? What is your base case? What does your base case return?

Comment: My base case returns null and I know that but I have no idea why it doesn't affect the actual list?

Comment: What do you mean _affect the actual list_? What is it you actually want to happen?

Comment: Which class is your linked list? Is it `Element`?

Comment: I want to delete the whole list but after calling this function debugger's still showing me the elements. It's in different class named List which has only one field: Element root ;)

Comment: I'm getting confuseder. When you say you want to "delete the whole list", do you mean you want to remove all elements from the List but leave the List itself in existence? Or do you want to just get rid of the whole thing?

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing in your delete method that actually deletes anything, i.e. it doesn't change the list and it doesn't change any Element in the list. All it does is search through the entire list to find an Element whose .next() is null, then it returns null.

You have to actually change a value somewhere.

So let's start with the delete(Element) method. As I've come to understand, it needs to take an Element, which is the head of a List, and delete all members of the List. Setting head = null won't work, as @Dan Getz has noted. You need to be able to get at the actual list, and all you have to work with is the Element, so the Element has to know which List contains it. And that means you need a myList field of type List in Element. Then your delete(Element head) method could just do

```
head.myList.deleteAll();
```

That requires a deleteAll() method in List, which would set root = null;

Or, if root is accessible from your delete(Element head) method, you could do

```
head.myList.root = null;
```

The point is that you somehow have to get to root, and passing it in to some other method doesn't do the job.

*Old answer below, doesn't quite fit the assignment requirements*

Start by removing the argument. You don't need to pass in head.

Then, in the body, just set head = null (assuming you have a field called head).

Return either null or the previous value of head, whichever matches your API.

Comment: Thanks so is it really that simple? I mean this was my homework and I figured out it can't be so easy so I used recursion but as you said I'll just set the argument to null and return the previous value

Comment: LOL never assume something must be harder. :-)

Comment: And BTW, if you like the answer, please consider accepting it.

Comment: No, setting the argument to `null` accomplishes nothing. Erick's suggestion was, if you have some *field* that you want to set `null`, then do that.

Comment: @Dan Getz
So how can I creat a method that deletes the whole list which head is given as an argument?

Comment: @Gregg start by telling us what your representation of a linked list is. Right now we're all just guessing.

Comment: Correct, @Dan Getz. I tacitly assumed that we were looking at a method in the LinkedList class, and explicitly assumed there was a field called "head" that pointed at the first element. But you're right, we don't know that. Context, please!

Comment: I'm sorry. So I have this class List{ Element root; ... }
class Element{int value; Element next; ...}
And I want to creat a method which will delete a list which head is given as an argument.

Comment: Alright so Erick's answer is perfect, you just weren't understanding that when he says "a field called head", he means your field `root`.

Comment: @Gregg could you edit that information about the `List` class into your original question? It would make the question/answer clearer for other people that arrive at this post.

Comment: And @DanGetz is correct, as long as you're putting this "delete()" method in your List class. But the idea of passing in the head of a List troubles me. You should be operating on the List, not the head of it. I get the impression I'm still missing the point.

Comment: But will it really work for any list? Should it look like this?
delete(Element head){ head=null;}

Comment: @ErickG.Hagstrom yeah... I would think the method would take no arguments and return nothing, in this case.

Comment: @Gregg a non-static method called on an object like `myList.delete()` has access to all the fields and methods of that object, without needing anything to be passed in as an argument.

Comment: @Dan Getz I know but in my assignment I have to pass an argument and it has to be a head of a list

Comment: I see your point but I think this also doesn't fit the assignment because I can't change the fields in given classes, I think I should somehow go through the list and just set each element to null but for instance using a loop might be difficult

Comment: That would work for all but the first one. root will still point at an Element, and the List won't be empty. If you have correctly understood the assignment and correctly communicated it to us, it cannot be done.

Comment: Yes. If all you have to work with is a List class that can't be changed and an Element that doesn't know what List it's in, you can't do it. The task is impossible.